# Dropdown(select) in Angular 12 is automatically selecting first item, after manual change in browser

Tags: html, angular, dropdown, html-select, onchange

Given following component HTML:

```
<select (change)="leagueChoosen($event)">
    <option disabled></option>
    <option *ngFor="let league of leagues.entries()" value={{league[1]}}> {{league[0]} </option>
</select>
```

where leagues are:

```
leagues:Map<string,number> = new Map([["PORTUGAL 1", 35],["BELGIUM 1", 3], ["GERMANY 2", 18]])
```

So, the problem is, whenever I select manually an item in my dropdown, the background logic is correct [the function leagueChoosen() ] is doing its job correctly, but, after that automatically first item in the list (the blank one) is selected automatically, and the dropdown text is consequently blank.

UPDATE:(Also I'm new at Angular)
There are 3 components: sidebar, content, wrapper(parent of the previous 2)

```
<!-- sidebar -->
<select (change)="leagueChoosen($event)">
  <option></option>
  <option *ngFor="let league of leagues.entries()" value={{league[1]}}>{{league[0]}}
</option>
</select>

<!-- content -->
<table>
   <caption>Football<app-button (btnClick)="Delete()" text="Delete" float="right"></app-button></caption>
   <thead>
    <th style="text-align: left;">{{data[0]==undefined?"":data[0].liga_header}}</th>
    <th colspan="3">Конечен тип</th>
    <th colspan="3">Голови</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let match of data">
        <td>{{match==undefined?"":match.broj}} - {{match==undefined?"":match.datum_vreme.substring(6,match.datum_vreme.length - 2) | date:"HH:mm"}} - {{match==undefined?"":match.tim1}} - {{match==undefined?"":match.tim2}}</td>
        <td>{{match==undefined?"":match.k1}}</td>
        <td>{{match==undefined?"":match.kx}}</td>
        <td>{{match==undefined?"":match.k2}}</td>
        <td>{{match==undefined?"":match.kgg3plus}}</td>
        <td>{{match==undefined?"":match.k0do2}}</td>
        <td>{{match==undefined?"":match.k3plus}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
 <!-- wrapper -->
 <div class='sidebar'>
 <app-sidebar (liClick)="leagueChoosen($event)"></app-sidebar>
 </div>
 <div class='content'>
 <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let league of data"><app-content 
         (dlt)="Delete(league)" 
         [data]="league">
     </app-content>
     </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is kinda React way of doing things. Could you maybe use Reactive Forms or Template Driven Forms?

To address the problem I guess I need to know whole template (and maybe all parents up into the root) in which this select is rendered. My suspicion is it is nested in an *ngFor loop and that re-renders when you select the league.

Comment: leagues are heard coded, just for an example(exercise). But later they will be, taken from an external "server" ... . This component(sidebar) is used in following (wrapper) component)`<div class='sidebar'>
    <app-sidebar (liClick)="leagueChoosen($event)"></app-sidebar>
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're looping over `leagues.entries()` which re-runs on every template check, which happens after the (change) callback. Therefore the selected DOM element is replaced since `entries` creates new objects every time. By default `ngFor`uses object reference to check for equality and since the objects are recreated they are not equal and the selected element is recreated.

One fix is to indeed use `[(ngModel)]` on the `<select>` but it does not address the source of the problem.

To make it cleaner you should use `trackBy`.

In your component TS code

```
// return the unique league key
trackLeagues(leagueEntry) { return leagueEntry[1] }
```

In the template

```
*ngFor="let league of leagues.entries(); trackBy: trackLeagues"
```

this should make sure that the selected `<option>` element is not replaced.

*Personal hint - I still think it would be best to use an `FormControl` and subscribe to its `valueChanges`. To describe how goes well beyond the scope of this answer.*

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is in your html where you didn't provide default value to `select` box.

Try below version:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="'35'" (change)="leagueChoosen($event)">
  <option></option>
  <option *ngFor="let league of leagues.entries()" [value]="league[1]">{{league[0]}}
  </option>
</select>
```